# How do I sync textArea /fields with, monster animation, also the code?

Tags: java, javafx

I have three triangles and three squares, each representing a monster. At a random dice roll one at a time is selected, the selected monster then moves to the middle of the screen (used a Pane, not the problem works fine) and then battles three rounds, each of which display in two textFields the dice rolls and in one textArea the actions in the battle, "Monster 1 struck monster 2 dealing him 2 damage(damage= difference of the dice rolls). After the three rounds the monster moves back into position, which I have moveBack() coded just not implemented, because I am stuck right here. The problem is the code just runs through I think. I don't know what to do to get it to stop and allow the first battle to happen before moving on.

```
public void playTheMonsterGame() {
    Timeline time = new Timeline();
    String[] hydNames = {"Heisenberg", "Jesse", "Todd"};
    String[] zexNames = {"Tuco", "Gustavo", "Lydia"};        

    dice.setMonsters1and2();// sets which monster we want for switch 
    switch (dice.monsterNum1) {
        case 1:
            trian.moveTri1();
            break;
        case 2:
            trian.moveTri2();
            break;
        case 3:
            trian.moveTri3();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    switch (dice.monsterNum2) {
        case 1:
            square.moveSquare1();
            break;
        case 2:
            square.moveSquare2();
            break;
        case 3:
            square.moveSquare3();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    dice.rollDice(); // random number generator generates all three rounds at once
    rollBox1 = ("Roll: " + dice.rolls[0][0] + ", " + dice.rolls[0][1] + ", " + dice.rolls[0][2] + ", " + dice.rolls[0][3]);
    rollBox2 = ("Roll: " + dice.rolls[3][0] + ", " + dice.rolls[3][1] + ", " + dice.rolls[3][2] + ", " + dice.rolls[3][3]);
    roll1.setText(rollBox1);
    roll2.setText(rollBox2); //roll is the text field
    int damage1;

    if (dice.total1a < dice.total4a) {
        damage1 = dice.total4a - dice.total1a;
    } else {
        damage1 = dice.total1a - dice.total4a;
    }
    System.out.println(damage1);
    trian.shrink(damage1);
    //jumboTron.setText(names[dice.monsterNum1]);
 }
```

I had it in a do while loop but that does not work obviously

also here is the triangle class for move so u know what i am working with:

```
public class Triangle {

public final Timeline timeline = new Timeline();

public void moveTri1() {
    timeline.setCycleCount(1);
    timeline.setAutoReverse(false);
    final KeyValue kvX = new KeyValue(tri1.layoutXProperty(), 274);
    final KeyValue kvY = new KeyValue(tri1.layoutYProperty(), 180);
    final KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), kvX, kvY);
    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf);
    timeline.play();
}

public void moveTri2() {
    timeline.setCycleCount(1);
    timeline.setAutoReverse(false);
    final KeyValue kvX = new KeyValue(tri2.layoutXProperty(), 274);
    final KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), kvX);
    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf);
    timeline.play();
}

public void moveTri3() {
    timeline.setCycleCount(1);
    timeline.setAutoReverse(false);
    final KeyValue kvX = new KeyValue(tri3.layoutXProperty(), 274);
    final KeyValue kvY = new KeyValue(tri3.layoutYProperty(), 180);
    final KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), kvX, kvY);
    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf);
    timeline.play();
}

public void moveBack() {
    timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.setAutoReverse(false);
    final KeyValue kvX = new KeyValue(tri1.layoutXProperty(), 90);
    final KeyValue kvY = new KeyValue(tri1.layoutYProperty(), 60);
    final KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), kvX, kvY);
    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf);
    timeline.play();
}

public void shrink(int damage) {
    double damPoints = damage/25.0;
    double damRescale = 25.0 - damPoints;
    System.out.println(damage+ " "+damPoints +" "+ damRescale);
    /*if(damRescale<=0)
        tri1.visibleProperty().setValue(false);
    else{
    tri1.setScaleX(damRescale);
    tri1.setScaleY(damRescale);}*/
 }
}
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. If you want to execute code at certain points in a timeline, you can create a `KeyFrame` that [specifies a time in the timeline and an event handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/KeyFrame.html#KeyFrame-javafx.util.Duration-javafx.event.EventHandler-javafx.animation.KeyValue...-); the event handler is executed at the specified time. And you can use [`setOnFinished`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#setOnFinished-javafx.event.EventHandler-) to execute code when the timeline ends.

Comment: Well you answered it pretty effectively. I try as hard as I can to be clear as possible on this website. I am learning how to talk in the community because I do need the help. So I do appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> ~~~>Part 1

Every time you call `moveTri1` `moveTri2` `moveTri3` and `moveBack` you are adding new keyFrames on TimeLine.Dunno if that is what you need but if not use :

```
  timeline.getKeyFrames().clear();
```

on the start of your methods to clear the previous KeyFrames existed in timeline.

> ~~~>About moveBack method

1)  In the first line of moveBack method you set :

```
timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
```

so the timeline will start again and again.But when the monster want to moveBack it does it one time not multiple times.So it may need to be:

```
timeline.setCycleCount(1);
```

2)You moveBack only triangle1?If the monster moved forward was triangle2?You have to save which monster moved forward before calling moveBack() method for the given monster.

Comment: thank you forgot this question but that helps with my android program lol